# Term document entropy calculation

Tags: r, term-document-matrix, quanteda

Using `dtm` it is possible to take the term frequency.

How is it possible or is there any easy way to calculate the [entropy](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.8278&rep=rep1&type=pdf)? It is giving higher weight to the terms with less frequency in some documents.

```
entropy = 1 + (Σj pij log2(pij)/log2n

pij = tfij / Σj tfij
```

tfij is the number of times word i occurs in document j.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function for doing that, although it could be improved by maintaining sparsity in the p_ij and log computations (this is how `dfm_tfidf()` is written for instance).  Note that I changed the formula slightly since (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis#Mathematics_of_LSI among other sources) there should be a minus in front of the sum.

```
library("quanteda")
textstat_entropy <- function(x, base = exp(1), k = 1) {
    # this works because of R's recycling and column-major order, but requires t()
    p_ij <- t(t(x) / colSums(x))

    log_p_ij <- log(p_ij, base = base)
    k - colSums(p_ij * log_p_ij / log(ndoc(x), base = base), na.rm = TRUE)
}

textstat_entropy(data_dfm_lbgexample, base = 2)
#        A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H        I        J        K 
# 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.045226 1.045825 1.117210 1.173655 1.277210 1.378934 
#        L        M        N        O        P        Q        R        S        T        U        V 
# 1.420161 1.428939 1.419813 1.423840 1.436201 1.440159 1.429964 1.417279 1.410566 1.401663 1.366412 
#        W        X        Y        Z       ZA       ZB       ZC       ZD       ZE       ZF       ZG 
# 1.302785 1.279927 1.277210 1.287621 1.280435 1.211205 1.143650 1.092113 1.045825 1.045226 1.000000 
#        ZH       ZI       ZJ       ZK 
# 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
```

This matches the weight function in the **lsa** package, when the base is *e*:

```
library("lsa")
all.equal(
    gw_entropy(as.matrix(t(data_dfm_lbgexample))),
    textstat_entropy(data_dfm_lbgexample, base = exp(1))
)
# [1] TRUE
```